# Want that button retains the number as text and makes it zero after 1 day

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview, counter

I have an activity. It contains horizontal `RecyclerView` that contains a `Button` and I want to use this `Button` as counter when I press it. I want this button to retain this number as text and make it zero after 1 day for example. What is the best way to save this value and how to check for 1 day?

Comment: use SharedPreferences to store the number and Calendar to compare the current date/time

Comment: use alarmmanager with shared preferences...

Comment: how to use alarmmanager with shared preferences